# iframe scrolling on ios within a fixed div not working

Tags: ios, iframe, scroll, fixed

Surely there must be a fix for this! I have tried several options which were solved in the past, but still none of them are working now.

The latest one I've found was this;

Wrap the iframe within a div and apply the scrolling css.

```
.scroller {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}
```

Then, detect the content height of the iframe using javascript, and set the iframe's height the same as the content height. So after the page has loaded, the html would look like this;

```
<div class="scroller">
    <iframe src="path_to_your_page" style="height: 1672px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

This works.... ONLY IF the iframe is from the same domain, otherwise you will get the cross-origin frame error.

Any ideas out there that still work ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have  in your web.config file if you are using asp.net.  Otherwise, make sure the header doesn't exist in your website [as documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).